# NoSuchMethodError when using Infinispan Query API

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan, in-memory-database

I am trying to do a query in infinispan using the hibernate and the lucene. But I get No such method exception. Below is my dependency, code and the exception

MY POM DEPENDENCY

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <infinispan.version>LATEST</infinispan.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-cachestore-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-embedded-query</artifactId>
            <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the cache initialization and structure. I have an mysql store which has data from which I am preloading.

```
EmbededCache embededCache = new EmbededCache();
                ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                b.eviction().maxEntries(100l);
                b.indexing().enabled(true).addProperty("default.directory_provider", "ram");
                b.persistence().addStore(JdbcStringBasedStoreConfigurationBuilder.class)
                    .preload(true)
                   .fetchPersistentState(false)
                   .ignoreModifications(false)
                   .purgeOnStartup(false)
                   .table()
                   .createOnStart(false)
                   .dropOnExit(false)
                   .createOnStart(false)
                   .tableNamePrefix("SIMULATOR.SCRIPS")
                   .idColumnName("SCRP_NAME").idColumnType("VARCHAR(255)")
                   .dataColumnName("SCRP_DETAILS").dataColumnType("BLOB")
                   .timestampColumnName("SCRP_LAST_UPDATED").timestampColumnType("BIGINT")
                   .connectionPool()
                   .connectionUrl("jdbc:mysql://ip:3306")
                   .username("user")
                   .password("password")
                   .driverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                final Configuration config = b.build();

                EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(config);
                Cache<String, ScripDetails> cache = cacheManager.getCache();


                ScripDetails scripDetails = new ScripDetails();
                scripDetails.scripName = "ICICIBANK";
                scripDetails.open = 2050;
                scripDetails.high = 2030;
                scripDetails.low = 1988;
                scripDetails.close= 2010L;
                scripDetails.volume = 50550;
                scripDetails.turnover= 51515L;
                scripDetails.date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

                cache.put("ICICIBANK",scripDetails);

                SearchManager sm = Search.getSearchManager(cache);
                org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder builder = sm.buildQueryBuilderForClass(ScripDetails.class).get();

                Query luceneQuery = builder.keyword() .onField("scripName") .matching("INFY") .createQuery();

                CacheQuery cacheQuery = sm.getQuery( luceneQuery );

                // get the results:
                List<Object> found = cacheQuery.list();

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.validateSettings(II)V
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50PostingsFormat.<init>(Lucene50PostingsFormat.java:412)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50PostingsFormat.<init>(Lucene50PostingsFormat.java:403)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.<clinit>(PostingsFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40Codec.<init>(Lucene40Codec.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:125)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.initializeIndexIfNeeded(DirectoryHelper.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.RAMDirectoryProvider.start(RAMDirectoryProvider.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildIncrementalSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.MutableSearchFactory.addClasses(MutableSearchFactory.java:233)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.SearchFactoryHandler$1.execute(SearchFactoryHandler.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.TransactionHelper.runSuspendingTx(TransactionHelper.java:23)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.SearchFactoryHandler.updateSearchFactory(SearchFactoryHandler.java:80)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.SearchFactoryHandler.handleOnDemandRegistration(SearchFactoryHandler.java:55)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.SearchFactoryHandler.updateKnownTypesIfNeeded(SearchFactoryHandler.java:42)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.QueryInterceptor.updateKnownTypesIfNeeded(QueryInterceptor.java:268)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.QueryInterceptor.processPutKeyValueCommand(QueryInterceptor.java:455)
    at org.infinispan.query.backend.QueryInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(QueryInterceptor.java:165)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitNonTxDataWriteCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:44)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.updateStoreStatistics(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:177)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:44)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.executeCommandAndCommitIfNeeded(CacheImpl.java:1617)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.putInternal(CacheImpl.java:1097)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.put(CacheImpl.java:1089)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.DecoratedCache.put(DecoratedCache.java:522)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.preloadKey(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:658)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.access$000(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:70)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl$1.processEntry(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore$2.call(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:350)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore$2.call(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.WithinThreadExecutor.execute(WithinThreadExecutor.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore.process(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:317)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.preload(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:218)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:850)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:599)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:554)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:424)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:397)
    at com.tlab.EmbededCache.main(EmbededCache.java:55)

May 07, 2015 8:01:49 AM org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore process
ERROR: ISPN000252: Error executing parallel store task
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: Unable to preload!
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore.process(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:364)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.preload(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:218)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:850)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:599)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:554)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:424)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:397)
    at com.tlab.EmbededCache.main(EmbededCache.java:55)
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: Unable to preload!
```

Comment: My bet is that you have multiple Lucene versions in your classpath. I'd suggest checking output of `mvn dependency:tree` and try to locate the different lucene dependencies. Really, you should be using the one suggested by Infinispan Query module, the rest of versions should be excluded (see [maven dependency exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html))

Answer (score 1):

This exception is a bit weird but maybe you could try the following things:

- Use newer version of all Infinispan artifacts, I advice upgrading to 7.2.1.Final.
- Please make sure that all Infinispan artifacts have the same version (so far I can see you are mixing LATEST and 7.0.0.CR2)
- Infinispan 7.2.1.Final is compatible with [Lucene 4.8.1, 4.9.0, 4.10.0, 4.10.1, 4.10.2](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_lucene_compatibility), so I highly recommend using those versions instead.

Comment: Hi altanis, great answer but needs a little correction on the Lucene versions. The versions you list are the ones compatible with the Infinispan Lucene Directory, but Hibernate Search (used by Infinispan Query and in the question) strictly requires a Lucene version from the 4.10.x line.